# Creating & accessing Arrays dynamically in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I'm developing an ios app and need to be able to somehow create arrays during runtime, add them to the mainDataArray and access them later on to be able to add new objects to them if I need to. 
Is that even possible or do I need to create 100 array properties and initialize them 1 by 1 when I need them? 
And if it works how could it be done?

Problem solved

Comment: Your question reads as though you don't know much about programming at all. I'd recommend you sit and do some tutorials before continuing with anything else.

Comment: I guess my question was a little too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible depends on you need but you can create array on runtime ( mutable or imutable ).

Here's a snippet:

```
//init
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];


//on demend
NSMutableArray *newArr = [NSMutableArray array];
[newArr addObject:myObject];
[arr addObject:newArr];


//pulling my object

Object *obj = [[arr objectAtIdex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm

Comment: Please mark my question as correct and upvote :)